# Single quote mark spacing problem

Tags: letterspacing

Using ShareLaTex, when I enter the line:
`. . . range of \textquoteleft interpretive tendencies\textquoteright or adjacent . . .` 
The result that comes back is:

> . . . range of 'interpretive tendencies'or adjacent . . .

where I need to have it display:

> . . . tendencies' or adjacent . . .

with space between ' and "or".
Should I be using a different command here or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Isn't it easier typing ``range of `interpretive tendencies' or adjacent``?

Comment: yes . . . I did some more research and saw that using the grav mark ` along with a right single quote ' produced the result I wanted. I think the \textquoteleft and \textquoteright commands must be left over from earlier versions of the software but are no longer properly supported and thus not properly working. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, LaTeX gobbles all spaces after any command. So, you can have three solutions here:

1. Add a forced space after the right quote by using `\` after `\textquoteright` followed by a space.
2. Simply use `'` instead of `\textquoteright`.
3. Use the `\xspace` command from `xspace` package to get *intelligent* spaces.

See the solutions below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xspace}

\begin{document}


\textquoteleft interpretive tendencies\textquoteright\ or adjacent 

`interpretive tendencies' or adjacent 

\textquoteleft interpretive tendencies\textquoteright\xspace or adjacent 


\end{document}
```

Comment: #1 came in handy for another similar situation – thanks much! I will keep the other points in mind . . .

Answer (score 1):

Use the csquotes package for a semantic, configurable and language aware quoting command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\begin{document}

range of \enquote*{interpretive tendencies} or adjacent

\end{document}
```

[image]